# Failed to `pip install numpy` in pypy2 virtual environment on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, numpy, pip, pypy

I build a virtual environment of **PyPy 5.3.1 with GCC 4.6.3** on **Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1 LTS**, and **Python 2.7.10** is the base interpreter. 
When I do `pip install numpy` in this virtual environment the following error occurrs:

> Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy ... error
>     Complete output from command /home/wyx/pypy2env/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-LSedyl/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpMpCaUZpip-wheel- --python-tag pp253:
>     Running from numpy source directory.
>     blas_opt_info:
>     blas_mkl_info:
>       libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu']
>       NOT AVAILABLE .............................
>   Command "/home/wyx/pypy2env/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-DI6BFD/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NIYDW7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/wyx/pypy2env/include/site/python2.7/numpy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DI6BFD/numpy/

`pip list` is

> cffi (1.7.0)
>   greenlet (0.4.9)
>   pip (8.1.2)
>   readline (6.2.4.1)
>   setuptools (21.2.1)
>   wheel (0.29.0)

Answer (score 0):

PyPy has its own working version of `numpy`. Instructions for installation are documented on [its repo](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy).